# how to attach file to the email from /data folder of the device

Tags: android

I am trying to attach the file from the /data folder of the device.

I have successfully created "abc.txt" in /data folder, I can see the file at that place.

I am using below code to send email:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{abc@gmail.com});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
       Uri.parse(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/abc.txt"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello..");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, email_chooser_title));
```

but I am unable to receive the attachments..

pl. let me know what's the mistake I have done..

thanks.

Comment: You dont get any errors? It just sends, you receive the email, but no attachment?

Comment: I haven't get any errors. It just sends without any attachments.

Answer (score 3):

You must copy the file to the external directory (aka SD Card). It's because the email application cannot access your data directory (in the same way that you can't access other app's data directory)

Comment: Yes, if in root mode, then you can read files from /data/ folder... otherwise you have to use /sdcard

Comment: This is not technically true; you can put a world-readable file *in your application's folder* under /data or wherever that particular android device provides applications with internal storage and an email application _should_ be able to read it, though there have been versions of the gmail app that refused to do so (even though the operating system would let them) unless pointed there with some /../../ type path trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
PATH=sdCard.toString()+"/abc.txt";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("**/**");// or intent.setType("text/plain");
String[] recipients={"abc@gmail.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+PATH));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello..");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,""));
```

Make sure there is abc.txt file in your Device/Emulator's sdcard.

Also include these two permissions in your project's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Android: Attaching files from internal cache to Gmail](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974) (with some modifications that allows you to run this code on Lollipop).

Basically you need to implement your own class that extends ContentProvider (say CachedFileProvider, see below), and add a next field in manifest (inside /application tag):

```
<provider
        android:name=".CachedFileProvider" 
        android:authorities="com.your.app.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" />
```

When opening a mail chooser, use next code:

```
File f = getLocalFileToSend();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + f.getName());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // Grant permissions to read.
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

The code for CachedFileProvider:

```
package ...;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;


public class CachedFileProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "CachedFileProvider";

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "CachedFileProvider";

    // The authority is the symbolic name for the provider class.
    // Should match one in the manifest file.
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.your.app.provider";

    // UriMatcher used to match against incoming requests
    private UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        // Add a URI to the matcher which will match against the form
        // 'content://com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach.provider/*'
        // and return 1 in the case that the incoming Uri matches this pattern
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*", 1);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Log.v(TAG, "Called with uri: '" + uri + "'." + uri.getLastPathSegment());

        // Check incoming Uri against the matcher
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {

            // If it returns 1 - then it matches the Uri defined in onCreate
            case 1:

                // The desired file name is specified by the last segment of the path.
                String fileLocation = getContext().getCacheDir() + File.separator
                        + uri.getLastPathSegment();

                // Create & return a ParcelFileDescriptor pointing to the file
                // Note: I don't care what mode they ask for - they're only getting
                // read only
                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(
                        fileLocation), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                return pfd;

            // Otherwise unrecognised Uri
            default:
                Log.v(TAG, "Unsupported uri: '" + uri + "'.");
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Unsupported uri: "
                        + uri.toString());
        }
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Not supported / used / required for this example
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s,
                      String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String s, String[] as1,
                        String s1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the 4th line

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/data/abc.txt"));
```

If it is in sdcard:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/sdcard/data/abc.txt"));
```

Comment: Note the first will not work, because the application in question does not have permission to write anything _directly_ under /data, but only in the assigned subfolder within /data.  Another app's ability to read would be based on the permission set by whoever created the file, though _ability_ and _willingness_ to read are not quite the same thing in the case of the gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/abc.txt"` did you try using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/abc.txt"` ?

I feel this change should do the trick. Of course, for this to work, you have to have the file on the phone's/emulator's SD card.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code!!!!    


File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
PATH=sdCard.toString();
String path =PATH.replace("/mnt","") + "/abc.txt";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("**/**");// or intent.setType("text/plain");
String[] recipients={"abc@gmail.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://" +path));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello..");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,""));
```